# Ansible lookup plugin "password" does not save password in a file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

can anyone help ?
I tried to implement the Ansible password generator [enter link description here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/password_lookup.html#examples). The problem is that I don't see where the file for the passwords is stored/created after the (seemingly) successfully runs?
But when I remove the part `'credentials/' + item.0.client_username +` then I am able to see the file created (where my ansible code is).
The documentation in the link does not say much.
At the bottom is also the content of the default file.

```
  - name: Add Client
    solace_client_username:
      name: "{{ item.0.client_username }}"
      msg_vpn: "{{ msg_vpn }}"
      settings:
        clientProfileName: "{{ item.1.clientProfileName }}"
        aclProfileName: "{{ item.1.aclProfileName }}"
        password: "{{ lookup('password',  'credentials/' + item.0.client_username + 'password.dat length=15 chars=ascii_letters,ascii_uppercase,ascii_lowercase,digits') }}"
    with_subelements:
    - "{{ clients }}"
    - specs
```

default yml:

```
clients:
  - client_username: export-john-doe
    specs: 
      - aclProfileName: export-john-doe-profile
        clientProfileName: default
        enabled: true

  - client_username: staging-john-doe
    specs: 
      - aclProfileName: staging-john-doe-profile
        clientProfileName: default
        enabled: true
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Was the `credentials` created? Have you listed the files in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*Where the file for the passwords are stored?*"**

A: On the controller/master. The [lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) run always on master.

> *" ...  lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine."*

> *"Lookups are executed with a working directory relative to the role or play, as opposed to local tasks, which are executed relative the executed script."*

---

Your code should work fine. For example

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('password',
             'credentials/' + item.0.client_username + 'password.dat
             length=15
             chars=ascii_letters,ascii_uppercase,ascii_lowercase,digits') }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ clients }}"
    - specs
```

gives on the controller in the current directory

```sh
shell> tree credentials/
credentials/
├── export-john-doepassword.dat
└── staging-john-doepassword.dat

0 directories, 2 files

shell> cat credentials/export-john-doepassword.dat
bcpJprWLv3srojj

shell> cat credentials/staging-john-doepassword.dat
rnyTJ3qpZczY0Qc
```

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir Botka's answer above is correct. I just noticed that this creates another folder named "credentials" where the files for each password are located. The folder is under the root directory (where you run the ansible code from).